# Second law of thermodynamics about refrigerator

Tags: thermodynamics

`Suppose there exists a refrigerator that lowers the temperature of one kilogram of the ocean water by one degree. If the temperature difference between the two sources is 1$^\circ$C. Is it possible to know how much work is required to get it?

Comment: What do you mean by "two sources"?

Comment: What do  you mean by "the temperature of one kilogram of the ocean"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me what the "two sources" are and what you mean by "one kilogram of the ocean".

But in general in order to know the required work you would need to know the coefficient of performance (COP) of the refrigerator, which is defined as

$$COP=\frac{Q_L}{W}$$

Where $Q_L$ is the heat extracted from the ocean water and $W$ is the work required to do it.

Hope this helps.